# Render passed components render function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to understand how to call a passed components render function inside another function. Say i have two functions i'd like to call (A and B):

```
export const A = (value: any) => {
return (
    <div>{value}</div>
);}

export const B = (value: any) => {
return (
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Source</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {value.map((item: any) => {
                <span>
                    <td>{Object.keys(item)}</td>
                    <td>{Object.values(item)}</td>
                </span>
            })}
        </tbody>
    </table>
);}
```

I would like to pass these two components into another, and have the passed component render inside the receiving component. So if i pass them like this into the CollapsibleSection component:

```
export class MeasureSection extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }

  public render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {data && data.map(({ ValueA, ValueB }: any, index: number) =>
          <div key={index}>

          {ValueA && <CollapsibleSection
              isCollapsed={false}
              buttonText='A'
              collapsibleSection={<A value={ValueA} />}
            />}

            {ValueB && <CollapsibleSection
              isCollapsed={false}
              buttonText='B'
              collapsibleSection={<B value={ValueB} />}
            />}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CollapsibleSection component:

```
export class CollapsibleSection extends React.Component<any, {isCollapsed: boolean}> {
    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isCollapsed: this.props.isExpanded
        }
        this._toggleCollapse = this._toggleCollapse.bind(this);
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        const { isCollapsed } = this.state;
        const { buttonText, collapsibleSection } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <DefaultButton
                    onClick={this._toggleCollapse} className="CollapsibleSection"
                >
                    {isCollapsed ? <i className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronUp" aria-hidden="true" /> : <i className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronDown " aria-hidden="true" />}
                    &nbsp; {buttonText}
                </DefaultButton>
                {isCollapsed && collapsibleSection.props.value}
            </div>
        );
    }

    private _toggleCollapse() {
        this.setState({ isCollapsed: !this.state.isCollapsed })
    }
}
```

In the collapsibleSections render function, i would like to call the passed components render function. The line

> {isCollapsed && collapsibleSection.props.value}

allows me to render component A, but i'm not calling the render, i'm just extracting the value (?). That approach does not work for more complicated components like B. So how to call component A and Bs render function inside the CollapsibleSections render function? Is this approach the right way to pass components into another components or is there a smarter way?

Comment: can you explain why you want to call the render method of A and B, and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to wrap any component into a custom-made collapsible section which is pretty much a button toggling expand/collapse. So in this example i would like two collapsible sections, one containing the value in A, other containing the table and value in B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t have to call `collapsibleSection.props.value` just `collapsibleSection` like `{isCollapsed && collapsibleSection}` because the property `collapsibleSection` will contain your component.